# How to get node.js system CLI app location?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I have node.js CLI app which needs to execute rsync from inside of my app codebase. Here is the structure:

```
.
├── app.js
└── rsync
    └── mac
        └── rsync
```

The app is installed globally so it can be run from any folder. I need to find out how to execute rsync which is located inside of my app codebase. To do so I need to find out the app absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__dirname` - returns path to the app root ; The name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in.

More info: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `which` command to see the absolute path of an application.

```
> which rsync
/usr/bin/rsync
```